# Abrir archivo desde el sistema

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-basic

Buenas tardes tengo la duda de como podria abrir un archivo de excel desde el sistema con asp.net visual basic

Utilizo este codigo pero me genera error

```
      Dim myFileDialog As New Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog()
      Dim xSheet As String = ""

    With myFileDialog
        .Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx"
        .Title = "Open File"
        .ShowDialog()
        
    End With
    If myFileDialog.FileName.ToString <> "" Then
        Dim ExcelFile As String = myFileDialog.FileName.ToString
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres descargar un archivo? ¿Ubicación del archivo?

Comment: lo que quiero es cargar un gridview ya tengo el codigo solo la parte de buscarlo mediante un boton no eh podido

Comment: Hola Brandon, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines la imagen, y agregues el mensaje de error como texto, de esa manera será mejor recibida, y evitarás el cierre o recibir votos negativos, gracias.